# Wordpress shortcode not recognized after plugin update

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, nextgen-gallery

I am trying to render a gallery (NextGen Gallery) via an ajax callback, but for some reason, after updating my version of NextGen Gallery (Version 2.0.79), shortcodes no longer seem to exist.

The ajax callback to my method in functions.php is working but the shortcodes are just printing as plain text.  Running shortcode_exists:

```
shortcode_exists('nggallery')  ->  NO
shortcode_exists('ngg_images') -> NO
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Thank you

Comment: Interestingly, my shortcodes are working when placed directly into a template file.  WTF?!

Comment: try to reinstall the plugin, or perhaps the plugin shortcode has changed with the new version and you need to put an updated shortcode where the old ones are.